# Increment Char Array Pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is it possible to increment/advance a char array like I can a char pointer?

For example I can do this for a char pointer:

```
while (*cPtr) 
   printf("c=%c\n", *(cPtr++));
```

But I am not able to do this:

```
// char cArray[] = "abcde";
while (*cArray)
   printf("c=%c\n", *(cArray++));  // Compile error: 19 26  [Error] lvalue required as increment operand
```

The purpose is to be able to iterate over a char array when I dont know the length of the array. My thinking is that I just want to advance till I find a null character I guess unless theres an easier way?

```
char a[] = "abcde";
int index = -1;

while (a[++index]) 
   printf("c=%c\n", a[index]);
```

Comment: How is `cArray` defined? I guess `char[]` but better post it :)

Comment: C-"string"s are `0`-terminated `char`-arrays, but not every `char`-array is C-"string". Concluding form this: Not every (`char`-)array necessarily is `0`-terminated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to increment/advance a char array like I can a char pointer?

Unlike pointers, arrays are not lvalues and you can't modify it. That's a major difference between arrays and pointers.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So if I have a char array `char[]` and I dont know the length of it, how can I iterate over that array (if at all?)

Comment: Use `sizeof` to calculate the array size and then use array indexing. Read [c-faq: Arrays and Pointers](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look. I am looking for a efficient way where I dont calculate the size/length of the array and just iterate till the null character (see my edit in my post)

Comment: @JakeM: If done right the calculation of an array's number of elements is done on compile time, which I consider very efficient in terms of run-time. An exception to this might exists for VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like that:

```
char cArray[] = "abc def";
char *p = &cArray[0];

while (*p)
   printf("c=%c\n", *(p++));
```

Comment: This obviously works for C-"string"s only, as those are `0`-terminated. It won't work (`char`-)arrays in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // if you know the length
    printf("c=%c\n", a[i]);
```

or get the size with sizeof() and replace `i < 5` with `i < size`:

```
int size = (sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with success under keil uVision:

```
char buffer[512];
uint8_t var[512];  // uint8_t = integer 8bit
for(int i = 0; i < 128; i = i + 4)
sprintf(&buffer[i],"%03d,", var[y]); //this will put 4 bytes in buffer
```

Better way to do this:

```
char       buffer[128];
uint8_t int_buffer[24];  // gets updated in an interrupt - some sensors values
uint8_t          i = 0;
uint8_t  PrintSize = 0;

while(/*myFile is smaller than 1Mb..*/)
   {
    PrintSize = 0;
    i = 0;
    while(i < 23)
        {
        PrintSize += sprintf(buffer + PrintSize,"%01d,",int_buffer[i]);
        i++;
        }
        PrintSize += sprintf(buffer + PrintSize,"%01d\n", int_buffer[23]);

    //write buffer to a file in my app
   }
```

File content is like this:

41,1,210,243,120,0,210,202,170,0,14,28,0,0,0,1,85,0,5,45,0,0,0,1
40,1,215,255,119,0,215,255,170,0,14,37,0,0,0,1,85,0,5,46,0,0,0,1